# To move/match the coordinates of an image to a fixed coordinate of the parent container using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to move my relative image's coordinate dynamically  to get moved to a fixed pointer's coordinate which is absolute to it

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried to get the coordinates of pointer by state and the relative image which the width is unset ,needs to locate its coordinate to the pointers coordinate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are in a parent-child relationship, simply use CSS: position:absolute on the child. If they aren't in a relationship: You can use .getBoundingClientRect() on the element that you want to position your second element relative to:

```
let rect = yourPointerElement.getBoundingClientRect();
```

rect is an object that holds several information regarding the current position and boundaries, including:
{ x, y, width, height, top, right, bottom, left } in pixels.

You can now use this information to position your second element relative to it, using CSS (i.E. position:fixed) and changing top/bottom/left/right with JS.